# Can you burn a quantum fluid?

Tags: physical-chemistry, bose-einstein-condensate, quantum-chemistry, superfluidity

Perhaps more generally, can you have a chemical reaction between a quantum fluid (a sodium Bose-Einstein condensate for example) and another quantum fluid or a non-quantum fluid?

Or as a silly paraphrase: Could you use a superfluid as a fuel?

Comment: It would stop being a superfluid as it heated up.

Comment: Yes, after the reaction started at the very least. Looks like it's still an area of active research: [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.145301)